# How to remove a dynamic jQuery accordion element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, accordion

I have a dynamic jQuery accordion that adds different accordion elements depending on which button I press. So far so good, but I'm having trouble adding a delete button inside each element that can delete the newly created item. This is what I have so far:

```js
$('#accordion').accordion();

$( function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();

    //ADD NEW EMPATHIZE ELEMENT TO ACCORDION WITH BUTTON 1
    $('#addEmpathize').on('click', function() {
      let newEmpathize = document.createElement('section');
      let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
      let newDeleteBtn = document.createElement('div')
      let acc = document.getElementById('accordion');

      //CREATES NEW TITLE
      newEmpathize.innerHTML =
        "<div class='empathize'>" +
        "<div class='title'><i class=\"far fa-heart\">&nbsp</i>EMPATHIZE</div>" +
        "<div class='push-right'>" +
        "<span style='margin-right: 20px; font-size: 16px'><i class=\"far fa-times-circle\"></i></span>|<span style='margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px'><a><i class='fas fa-chevron-down rotate'></i></a></span>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>";

      //CREATES CONTENT INSIDE ACCORDION SECTION        
      newDiv.innerHTML = "<div class='inline'><div class='card'>ITEM 1</div><div class = 'card' > ITEM 2 < /div><div class='card'>ITEM 3</div > < /div>";

      //CREATES DELETE BUTTON
      newDeleteBtn.innerHTML = "<div><button class='delete'>Delete</button></div>"

      //APPENDS ELEMENTS TO ACCORDION AND REFRESHES
      acc.appendChild(newEmpathize);
      acc.appendChild(newDiv);
      acc.appendChild(newDeleteBtn);
      $("#accordion").accordion("refresh");
    });
    })

    //DELETE FUNCTION
    $('.delete').on('click', function() {
      $(this).closest(section).remove();
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="btn-box">
          <button id="addEmpathize" class="btn emp-btn"><i class="far fa-heart">&nbsp</i>Empathize</button>
          <button id="addDefine" class="btn def-btn"><i class="fas fa-bullseye">&nbsp</i>Define</button>
          <button id="addIdeate" class="btn idea-btn"><i class="far fa-lightbulb">&nbsp</i>Ideate</button>
          <button id="addPrototype" class="btn prot-btn"><i class="fas fa-pencil-ruler">&nbsp</i>Prototype</button>
          <button id="addTest" class="btn test-btn"><i class="fas fa-vial">&nbsp</i>Test</button>
        </div>

        <!-- START ACCORDION ELEMENT  -->
        <div>
          <div id="accordion"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- END ACCORDION ELEMENT -->

      </div>
    </body>
```

As you can see, the last few lines are the function to delete the closest section. However, it doesn't delete the element created, but instead, it breaks any new sections created. Any idea how I can fix this?

I'm only showing the code for one of the buttons, since they all work pretty much the same, except that the accordion contents are different. What's important is that they all add a different element to the SAME accordion.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the delegation approach like the following way:

```
$('body').on('click', '.delete', function(){.....
```

Also, you should use quotes around *section*.

I have updated the markup a bit to contain each group inside of a parent element:

**Demo:**

```js
//ADD NEW EMPATHIZE ELEMENT TO ACCORDION WITH BUTTON 1
$('#addEmpathize').on('click', function() {
  $('#accordion').accordion(); // added to initialize accordion
  let newEmpathize = document.createElement('section');
  let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  let newDeleteBtn = document.createElement('div')
  let acc = document.getElementById('accordion');

  //CREATES NEW TITLE
  newEmpathize.innerHTML =
    "<div class='empathize'>" +
        "<div class='title'><i class=\"far fa-heart\">&nbsp</i>EMPATHIZE</div>" +
        "<div class='push-right'>" +
            "<span style='margin-right: 20px; font-size: 16px'><i class=\"far fa-times-circle\"></i></span>|<span style='margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px'><a><i class='fas fa-chevron-down rotate'></i></a></span>" +
        "</div>" +
    "</div>";

    //CREATES CONTENT INSIDE ACCORDION SECTION        
    newDiv.innerHTML = "<div class='inline'><div class='card'>ITEM 1</div><div class='card'>ITEM 2</div><div class='card'>ITEM 3</div></div>";

     //CREATES DELETE BUTTON
    newDeleteBtn.innerHTML = "<div><button class='delete'>Delete</button></div>"

    //APPENDS ELEMENTS TO ACCORDION AND REFRESHES
    var parentEl = document.createElement('div'); // create an element as parent
    parentEl.classList.add('deleteParent'); // set class to the element
    parentEl.appendChild(newEmpathize);
    parentEl.appendChild(newDiv);
    parentEl.appendChild(newDeleteBtn);

    acc.appendChild(parentEl); // add the parent element
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion("refresh");
});

//DELETE FUNCTION
$('body').on('click', '.delete', function(){
   $(this).closest('.deleteParent').remove(); // remove the respective group
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="btn-box">
            <button id="addEmpathize" class="btn emp-btn"><i class="far fa-heart">&nbsp</i>Empathize</button>
            <button id="addDefine" class="btn def-btn"><i class="fas fa-bullseye">&nbsp</i>Define</button>
            <button id="addIdeate" class="btn idea-btn"><i class="far fa-lightbulb">&nbsp</i>Ideate</button>
            <button id="addPrototype" class="btn prot-btn"><i class="fas fa-pencil-ruler">&nbsp</i>Prototype</button>
            <button id="addTest" class="btn test-btn"><i class="fas fa-vial">&nbsp</i>Test</button>
        </div>

        <!-- START ACCORDION ELEMENT  -->
        <div>
            <div id="accordion"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- END ACCORDION ELEMENT -->

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough before! I've updated the question to show that the accordion element is already initialized, as all this is inside the accordion function. Your answer is great, but the thing is, I can't initialize a new accordion instance since there are 5 buttons, and they all add new elements with different content to the same accordion. The way it's working now, instead of deleting the entire accordion block, it's only deleting the collapsable contents and not the title bar.

Comment: @AlexanderHolmes, running your code produces the error *Uncaught TypeError: $(...).accordion is not a function*!!!